# How do i access a specific index of an element using ArrayList?

Tags: java

Say for example, I want to get the index of "w" in "howdy", or the "g", in "wasgood", how would i do that? The Arraylist .indexOf method only seems to return the entire element stored in the Arraylist

```
ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("hi");
list.add("howdy");
list.add("greetings");
list.add("wasgood");
list.add("squareup");
list.add("plurals");
```

Comment: Try to use chartAt() method

Comment: To get the index first you need to get the element from array list ..

Comment: could someone give me an example code?

Comment: @PrinceManiGupta Do we really need to convert to char array to get the index??

Comment: @AnoopLL.my bad.No need to do that.indexOf will save this effort.

Answer (score 4):

This gets you position in arraylist of greetings.

```
list.indexOf("greetings");
```

This get you position of letter in word.

```
"greetings".indexOf("t");
```

Answer (score 0):

`"howdy".getIndexOf("w");` will return the index of 'w' in "howdy".

Comment: how could I make it so that I can cycle through all the stored Strings, instead of typing out each one individually?

Comment: @Picklejar75if you want to cycle through the list, then you would have to find index of a particular character for every item of the list.

For example : You ll have to find index of 'w' in all the list items.
If you want to find the index of different characters in different items, then you have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to know the char index in a string.
What you should use is like "howdy".indexOf('w').
It has no relation to ArrayList. It is a method of String.